# What's the use of the "Sent Actions" option for an NSTextField?

Tags: click, interface-builder, nstextfield

In `Interface Builder`, when control-clicking on a `NSTextField`, the option `Sent Actions` is available. I thought it would trigger an action when clicking on my `NSTextField` (which is non-editable), but it doesn't work.

[image]

Any clue of the aim of this option?

Answer (score 2):

The explanations below describe how to connect an action to an object which will appear in the "Sent Actions" field. In your case that would be `NSTextField`. For example, here's a question on how to add a specific action to `NSTextField`: [Send action from NSTextField when on key up instead of return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003815/send-action-from-nstextfield-when-on-key-up-instead-of-return) .

All of this might not be relevant since you're working with a non-editable `NSTextField`. Nevertheless, if you did want to add a click action, there's a solution provide here: [Which delegate method should I use to respond to clicks on an NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684166/which-delegate-method-should-i-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-an-nstextfield).

- [How to connect a button to a method on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793636/1085891)

  > When you right-click on a button in a Mac nib, performClick: is under
  >   Received Actions; it’s not an event. The only entry under Sent Actions
  >   is “selector”, which is the only thing you can connect to an action on
  >   another object.
  >
  > Because there is only one “sent event”, you’ll normally just
  >   control-drag/right-drag from the control to the target and select the
  >   action rather than control-clicking, selecting the event and dragging
  >   from that.
- [Create the connection from the button to the action](http://camelbones.sourceforge.net/docs/getstarted/events.html)

  > Now, right-click (or ctrl-click) on the button you added earlier, to
  >   show its inspector panel. In that panel, you'll see a section titled
  >   "Sent Actions", with a single item shown; that item is titled
  >   "selector", because it hasn't yet been connected to an action method.
  >   To make the connection, drag from that item's target (the circle at
  >   the right) to the controller object in the document window.
- [Adding an action to a GUI item](http://www.bhecker.com/ip-lect10.ppt) - Slide 12/13

  > 1. Write the action code as a method of any class that IB knows (for example: ...AppDelegate or any class of your own making that you make
  >      known to IB)
  > 2. Click on the GUI item in the application window whose action you want to set
  > 3. Open the Connections Inspector
  >
  >    Under the Sent Actions listing you will see ‘selector’, for that item. Click on the empty circle to the right and drag it to the
  >      MainMenu.xib window to the class where the action method is
  >      implemented; release it there.
  >
  >    Upon release a listing of all implemented methods that can serve as actions is shown. Choose one with the mouse and click on it.
  >
  >    This process corresponds to the target-action pattern that we used in writing the app without IB. The action method must be written
  >      with one parameter of type id.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _txt_city.delegate = self;
    _txt_city.tag = 1000;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;        // return NO to disallow editing.
{
    if(textField.tag == 1000)
    {
        // Create event;
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return YES;
}
```